# Convert string to Json with powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I have a text file with rows like :

```
TRACE 2016-06-23 08:47:54,803 {"x":"0.0000179000","l":"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.34209)","a":"Get","p":"345","u":"dae824a6-144b-4135-a6fd-01584f06a27f","i":"10.0.2.166","s":"US","e":"start"}
```

It will be great if someone can help how to convert it to JSON with powershell (I tried it with ConvertTo-JSON , but without success.)

Comment: `ConvertTo-Json` serializes an arbitrary object to a JSON string, such as `ls | ConvertTo-Json`.  You probably want `ConvertFrom-Json`, which converts a JSON string into a custom object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# 'TRACE 2016-06-23 08:47:54,803 {"x":"0.0000179000","l":"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.34209)","a":"GetUserStartedWatchingMedias","p":"195","u":"dae824a6-144b-4135-a6fd-01584f06a27f","i":"10.0.2.166","s":"EU-WS-A-5","e":"start"}'

foreach ($row in  (Get-Content -LiteralPath C:\TEMP\IIS_Logs\IIS_Logs.txt ) )
{
    if ($row -like '*}')
    {
        $Arr = $row -split ' ' ;
        $Arr = $Arr -ne ' ' ;

        $RecordDate = $Arr[1]+' '+$Arr[2];
        $Json = $row.Substring($row.IndexOf("{"),($row.IndexOf("}")-$row.IndexOf("{")+1));
        ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $Json | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter "," -NoTypeInformation | Out-File 'C:\TEMP\IIS_Logs\test.txt'
    };
};
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not entirely clear what you want.  If you want a *valid* JSON string then just remove the first part of the string (this part: `TRACE 2016-06-23 08:47:54,803`) and your done:

```
$data = 'TRACE 2016-06-23 08:47:54,803 {"x":"0.0000179000","l":"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.34209)","a":"Get","p":"345","u":"dae824a6-144b-4135-a6fd-01584f06a27f","i":"10.0.2.166","s":"US","e":"start"}'

$json = $data.Substring($data.IndexOf("{"))
```

If you want to convert it from JSON to an object then you still need to convert the string into a valid JSON string and then you can simply do this:

```
$myObject = ConvertFrom-Json $json
```